# Determine browser language(s) in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am dissolving a rather big old library with various PHP helper functions that have amassed over time. I'm looking for Zend Framework based replacements for as many of these functions as possible.

My first candidate is a function that returns the users's *most preferred browser language* from the huge list that can be `http_accept_language`.

Does ZF have a function for that?

I realize [Zend_Translate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.additional.html) is able to somehow detect the browser language, but I am not seeing a publicly available function to actually get the language string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

here you go:

```
$locale = new Zend_Locale();

// if locale is 'de_AT' then 'de' will be returned as language
print $locale->getLanguage();

// if locale is 'de_AT' then 'AT' will be returned as region
print $locale->getRegion();
```

Comment: What happens if the preference is only "en" or "es"? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469629/zend-locale-zend-currency-region-code

Comment: I directly answered to your question.

Answer (score 9):

[`Zend_Locale`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.html) should be able to help, about that.

See the examples and explanations on the page [Using Zend_Locale](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.introduction.html) *(quoting)* :

> For most situations, `new
>   Zend_Locale()` will automatically
>   select the correct locale, with
>   preference given to information
>   provided by the user's web browser.

And there are a couple more details later on that page *(quoting)* :

> The search algorithm used by
>   `Zend_Locale` for automatic selection
>   of a locale uses three sources of
>   information: 
> **1.** `const
>   Zend_Locale::BROWSER` - The user's Web
>   browser provides information with each
>   request, which is published by PHP in
>   the global variable
>   `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`. if no matching
>   locale can be found, then preference
>   is given to `ENVIRONMENT` and lastly
>   `FRAMEWORK`. 
> **2.** `const
>   Zend_Locale::ENVIRONMENT` - PHP
>   publishes the host server's locale via
>   the PHP internal function
>   `setlocale()`. If no matching locale
>   can be found, then preference is given
>   to `FRAMEWORK` and lastly `BROWSER`.
>   
> **3.** `const
>   Zend_Locale::FRAMEWORK` - When Zend
>   Framework has a standardized way of
>   specifying component defaults
>   *(planned, but not yet available)*, then using this constant during
>   instantiation will give preference to
>   choosing a locale based on these
>   defaults. If no matching locale can be
>   found, then preference is given to
>   `ENVIRONMENT` and lastly `BROWSER`.

*(Advice : go read that page -- I will not copy-paste everything there is to read ^^ )*

**Edit :** And here's the portion of code that illustrates my comment :

```
$locale = new Zend_Locale();
var_dump($locale->getLanguage());
var_dump($locale->getRegion());
die;
```

Gives me :

```
string(2) "fr" 
bool(false)
```

Well, my browser is asking for french, without specifying a region ^^

Comment: Cheers @Pascal, on the long run I will be able to work with `Zend_Locale`. At the moment, though, I am just replacing the helper functions library in an existing application with its own locale handling, so I need to get hold of the actual ISO code.

Comment: Oh :-( too bad :-( ;;; humph... thiking about it : what about first instanciating the locale, letting ZF do its magic, and then calling the `getLanguage()` and/or `getRegion()` methods to get the locale's code ?

Comment: I've edited my answer to get a portion of code -- but I see I've been beaten to it by @henchman ^^

Comment: I'm going to accept @henchman's answer as he indeed beat you by a few seconds, but cheers @Pascal. It works perfectly, even with languages that are 100% not in any locale list.

Comment: No problem :-) Glad you have your solution :-)

Answer (score 5):

I've upvoted both answers. As an alternative to getting the language with `Zend_Locale` consider

- http://de3.php.net/manual/en/locale.acceptfromhttp.php or
- http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.http-negotiate-language.php

Comment: +1 for the first one : even if it's only available in PHP >= 5.3, using native functions is good *(and the intl classes are a great addition to PHP).*

Comment: I will accept the Zend based answer because that's what I asked for, but +1 because this really is nice and even built-in - 5.3.0 is too much to ask right now but won't in a year. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a possibility to force `Zend_Locale()` to get the first **full** locale (language code and region code, like 'en_US') instead of just the language code ('en')? If not, it's a problem to handle currencies because they need a full locale.

How do you handle this issue? I haven't found any acceptable solution for that problem yet and for me it seems like this should be a task for `Zend_Locale`, in `_prepareLocale($locale, $strict = false)` for example.