# Zend Locale & Zend_Currency: Region code

Tags: zend-framework, zend-locale, zend-currency

I am trying to create a connection between the Zend_Locale and the Zend_Currency using the browser language preferences.

BROWSER: en

```
$locale = new Zend_Locale(Zend_Locale::BROWSER);
Zend_Debug::Dump($locale->getLanguage());
Zend_Debug::Dump($locale->getRegion());
die;
```

Result:

```
string(2) "en"
bool(false)
```

BROWSER: en_US

```
$locale = new Zend_Locale(Zend_Locale::BROWSER);
Zend_Debug::Dump($locale->getLanguage());
Zend_Debug::Dump($locale->getRegion());
die;
```

Result:

```
string(2) "en"
string(2) "US"
```

Ho have I to solve this problem?

This is my plugin controller:

```
class MyProject_Controller_Plugin_Language extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

    public function routeShutdown(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
        $locale = new Zend_Locale(Zend_Locale::BROWSER);

        $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();

        // Check if the config file has been created
        $isReady = MyProject_Main::isReady();

        $module = $request->getModuleName ();

        if($module == "default"){   // set the right session namespace per module
            $ns = new Zend_Session_Namespace ( 'Default' );
        }elseif($module == "admin"){
            $ns = new Zend_Session_Namespace ( 'Admin' );
        }else{
            $ns = new Zend_Session_Namespace ( 'Default' );
        }

        // check the user request if it is not set, please get the old prefereces
        $lang = $request->getParam ( 'lang', $ns->lang );

        if(empty($lang)){                           // Get the user preference
            if(strlen($locale) == 2){               // Check if the Browser locale is formed with 2 chars
                $lang = $locale;
            }elseif (strlen($locale) > 4){          // Check if the Browser locale is formed with > 4 chars
                $lang = substr($locale, 0, 2);      // Get the language code from the browser preference
            }
        }

        // Get the translate language or the default language: en
        if(file_exists(PUBLIC_PATH . "/languages/$lang/$lang.mo")){
            $translate = new Zend_Translate(array('adapter' => "MyProject_Translate_Adapter_Gettext", 'content' => PUBLIC_PATH . "/languages/$lang/$lang.mo", 'locale'  => $lang, 'disableNotices' => true));
        }else{
            $translate = new Zend_Translate(array('adapter' => "MyProject_Translate_Adapter_Gettext", 'locale'  => $lang, 'disableNotices' => true));
        }

        $registry->set('Zend_Translate', $translate);
        $registry->set('Zend_Locale', $locale);

        if($isReady){
            $ns->langid = Languages::get_language_id_by_code($lang);
        }else{
            $ns->langid = 1;
        }

        $ns->lang = $lang;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the client's language preferences are a good first step, but won't help you in all cases. Even if they return a value, I would not use it to determine the appropriate currency as you described - users may set their preferred language/region to a foreign setting. Examples are expats and language learners. Though this may be an edge case, don't trust it to detect currency.

The most robust solution would be to use a geolocation service which also returns the currency for the location found, e.g. http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php.

The combination of both methods may also be a good solution. If they return conflicting values, offer the user a possibility to choose from the two found currencies (or from any other).

Comment: Hi I have updated my question adding the php code. As you can see I have avoid to set the currency as you have described before and I have handled the locale in that way but seems to me a rude way to do it. Any suggestion?